# How to convert a datetime to a date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I'm designing a class that takes a `date` argument defaulting to today. I understand `datetime.now()` gives the current timestamp, but am not able to find a way to convert the `datetime` instance to `date`. Obviously I can do `date(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().day)` but that's ugly, and in the off chance the code runs at the end of a day, month or year, will create an inconsistent instance of my class.

Python 3.x solutions only, please.

One option is using a static method.

```
@staticmethod
def _today():
    now: datetime = datetime.now()
    return date(now.year, now.month, now.day)

def __init__(self, start_date: date = _today(), bucket_size_hour: int = 1):
    pass
```

Comment: You can use `.date` and that should be enough?

Comment: Did you try `datetime.now().date()` or, perhaps,  `datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')` if you mean by `date` a string in the format `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: I wasn't of `datetime.date`. If one of you would care to post an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Everytime you are not sure what methods are available for an object, open an interactive Python session and type `dir(objectname)`. For `datetime`, for example, you can do `dir(datetime.datetime)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by adding `.date` at the end of the datetime object. Tweaking how you define `datetime` a litle bit like this should work for you:

```
datetime = datetime.today().date()
```

Output:

```
2019-12-26
```

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a `date.today()` but I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You are missing `()` after `.date`.

Comment: Yes, sorry and thanks, I copy-pasted the line. Thanks for the edit.